# Paho и условные аргументы

Tags: python

Условный оператор не выполняется, когда переменная в точности такая же, что и в условии

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe 




while(True):
    statusLight = subscribe.simple("Light/forvard", hostname="192.168.1.100",port=1883, auth {"username":"skorpia", "password":"n-1"})


    print("%s" % (statusLight.payload))
    if statusLight.payload == "b'0'":
        print("hello")
```

Comment: `"b'0'"` и `b'0'` не одно и то же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаком с данной библиотекой, но полагаю, что она нужна для работы с сетью.

Скорей всего `statusLight.payload` имеет тип `bytes`. Вы же сравниваете результат со **строкой** (`str`).

Вам необходимо заменить `"b'0'"` на `b'0'`.

Comment: Вполне возможно что из-за этого ошибка.